# Perl - Join on '\t' in single quotes

Tags: regex, perl

In my back end Perl code I receive delimiter in single quotes like

```
'\t'
```

when i try to use `JOIN` function on it like this

```
my $string = join ( $del, @aArray );
```

I get output with hardcoded `\t` between array values

```
My\tName\tIs\tDave
```

I tried to change the quotes to double quotes of `$del`  because `"\t"` works. So i tried to convert

```
qq{"$del"}
```

but it didnt work. When i do print on it, I get

```
'"\t"'
```

I also tried regex to no avail

```
$del =~ s/'/"/g;
```

Can anyone please tell me how to replace single quote with double?

Comment: What do you mean by _you receive_? Does some code you cannot control call your code with  `'\t'` as an argument? Please explain this a bit more detailed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This answer is based on an assumption** until the question is a bit more clear.

In case you are exposing a function, and someone is calling it passing the delimiter as `'\t'`, there are several ways you can deal with it. I have sorted them from worst to best solution.

- string-`eval` it. This is **dangerous** because you don't know what kind of code could be passed in.

  ```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use feature 'say';
  sub my_join {
      my ($del, @stuff) = @_;

      return unless $del;
      return if length $del > 2;
      $del = eval qq{"$del"};

      say join $del, @stuff;
  }

  my_join( '\t', qw(My name Is Dave) );
  ```

  This will give the right output, but it's not save because you cannot control the input. Someone might do bad stuff. That's why there is the `length` check. Of course then a delimiter like `...` is not possible any more. That might be something you want.

  **Please don't use the `eval`,** I just put it here for a complete answer.
- Use a lookup table.

  ```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use feature 'say';

  sub my_join {
      my ($del, @stuff) = @_;

      my %lookup = (
         '\t' => "\t",
         '\n' => "\n",
      );

      $del = $lookup{$del} if exists $lookup{$del};

      say join $del, @stuff;
  }

  my_join( '\t', qw(My name Is Dave) );
  ```

  With this solution, you can exactly control which delimiters you want to convert. All others will be used *as is*. Or you could just not allow them if they don't exist in your lookup hash.
- See [Neil Massons's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34177681/1331451) for the best approach, the short regular expression substitution. I prefer it.

Answer (score 5):

How do you "receive" the delimiter?  If `\t` is somehow being passed to your perl program as a string, then no quoting inside your perl program will convert it to a tab character.  Instead you would have to detect the string containing `\t` and convert it to a tab character.

```
$del =~ s/\\t/\t/;
```

In this substitution, the match is for an actual backslash followed by a `t`.

Answer (score 1):

The code `'\t'` produces the two-character string `\t`.
The code `"\t"` produces the single character string Tab.

Perhaps you want the following:

```
$del = "\t" if $del eq '\t';
```

But that begs the question... What if you wanted the separator to be the two characters `\` and `t`? The following is a solution to provide a generic escaping mechanism similar to the one used by double-quote string literals:

```
my %tr = (
   n => "\n",
   r => "\r",
   t => "\t",
   # ...
);

$str =~ s{\\(?:(\W)|(.))}{
   defined($1) ? $1 :
   defined($tr{$2}) ? $tr{$2} :
   do { warn("Unrecognized escapes \\$2"); "\\$2" }
}seg;
```